# Loading property file from system properties with default path in Spring context

Tags: spring

I am trying to load a properties file (located outside of the war) in my Spring context with a path coming from the system properties.

If that system property doesn't exist or the path is not found, I'd like to fallback to a default properties file included in my .war.

Here is the specific part of my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" location="file:${config.dir}/config/server.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="false" location="classpath:config/server.properties"/>
```

Problem is that when config.dir isn't found in the system properties, an Exception is thrown saying that the resolver failed to find that property.

And even the case it would resolve, I'm pretty sure that the second line would make so that the properties loaded in the file given in parameter are replaced by the one in the default file, which is the opposite of what I want to do.

I'm using Spring 4.x with xml only configuration.

Is it possible to do what I want ?
I'm aware of the @Conditional for a Java based configuration but I'm only able to use the xml way to respond to the criteria of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use 2 placeholders, use a single one, the `location` property takes a `,` separated list of files to load.

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true" location="file:${config.dir}/config/server.properties,classpath:config/server.properties"/>
```

However the `config.dir`property has to be available else the loading will blow up.

Another solution would be to use an [`ApplicationContextInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html) and depending on the availability of the `config.dir` property load or not to load the additional file.

```
public class ConfigInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer {

    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        MutablePropertySources mps = env.getPropertySources();

        mps.addLast(new ResourcePropertySource("server.properties", "classpath:config/server.properties"));

        if (env.containsProperty("config.dir")) {
            String configFile = env.getProperty("config.dir")+"/config/server.properties";
            Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource(configFile);
            if (resource.exists() ) {
                mps.addBefore("server.properties", new ResourcePropertySource(resource));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you only need an empty `<context:property-placeholder />` element.

Added advantage is that you could specify a default `config.dir` in your default properties and have that overridden by a system or environment property.