# how can i access config.properties file which is placed outside the project inside applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The below bean is placed in `applicationContext.xml` file and i need to read the `host`, `port`, `username`, `password` values from `config.properties` file which is placed at some `xyz` path. How to read it in `applicationContext.xml`?

```
<bean id="ftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value=""/>
        <property name="port" value=""/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring application context external properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270290/spring-application-context-external-properties)

Comment: ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640453/loading-property-file-from-system-properties-with-default-path-in-spring-context