# override values in application.properties files from command line

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have apllication.properties files in java web application which contains these properties.

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:19095/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test123
```

But I want to override these properties (except driverClassName) while starting tomcat server.
I'm trying to set these variables from command line, but it's not working.

tomcat version : 7.0.63

Comment: How are you launching your application and how exactly are you trying to set the variables from command line? Maybe you're using the wrong syntax. This: `java -Dspring.datasource.username=newUsername -jar yourjar.jar` should work for a Spring Boot application, for example.

Comment: @walen thnx for the reply.  I was using the wrong syntax. Setting all variables in   CATALINA_OPTS and starting my tomcat using catalina.sh start. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a property placeholder with config directory specified by a system parameter:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${configLocation}/database.properties:defaultDatabase.properties" />
```

Then start the tomcat with:

```
-DconfigLocation=/opt/config
```

see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html and also [Loading property file from system properties with default path in Spring context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640453/loading-property-file-from-system-properties-with-default-path-in-spring-context)

Comment: i'm not using xml based configuration in my application. Username, password and url are dynamic.

Comment: What does "dynamic mean", why can't they be in a config file on the tomcat server box?