# How to load system properties in Spring for properties file location

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I am working on a Spring application where the properties file will be packaged inside the the .war file for deployment.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

However, I would like to be able to override them with another file that can be specified in standalone.xml as a system property:

```
</extensions>

<system-properties>
    <property name="CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION" value="/path/to/application.properties"/>
</system-properties>
```

This was my solution,

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties,
                                        file:///${CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION}" />
```

but apparently Spring is unable to find it

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION} (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Does anyone has any idea how I might fix it? Is there another way Spring accesses the system properties?

Comment: It is actually working, it was my fault as I was starting with the wrong standalone.xml version that did not have the property configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually possible in `Spring` to override certain properties by specifying a `system property` location to another file using this solution:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:alarm_notification.properties, file:///${CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION}" />
```

If a certain property is not overridden inside the file located at `CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION`, the value from `application.properties` will be used instead.

Just make sure to have the following configuration in the `standalone.bat` file used to start the server:

```
</extensions>

<system-properties>
    <property name="CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION" value="/path/to/application.properties"/>
</system-properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to file namespace for that as follows:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>file:/myFolder/folder/path/application.properites</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

or as follows:

```
<context:property-placeholder locations="file:/myFolder/folder/path/application.properites"/>
```

Comment: I already know this, my question was about setting this value dynamically, as a system property and then making Spring load it.

Comment: Refer to the following ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640453/loading-property-file-from-system-properties-with-default-path-in-spring-context